# Command in sage like permsupport in maple

Tags: group-theory, permutation-cycles, sagemath

I am learning how to compute with sage, I am very much used to maple. So I have the following code in Maple and want to covert it in Sage. So here is my problem.
So I am working in a symmetric group say for example $S_3$ and I want all the monotonic transposition tuples
Monseq(3) = $$[[(2,3),(2,3)],[(2,3),(1,3)],[(1,3),(2,3)],[(1,3),(1,3)],[(1,2),(2,3)],[(1,2),(1,3)],[(1,2),(1,2)]
 $$
that is the tuples $(a,b)(c,d)$ such that $b\leq d$, so my programme in maple I have written below can compare the inequality and give back the list.
In sage I used

```
G = SymmetricGroup(3)
g = G((1,2))
C = ConjugacyClass(G,g)
```

But then I cannot compare the elements of C, something like I did with ${\bf{PermSupport}}$ in maple, Is there any similar function in Sage to do it? I put my code for maple below.

```
Mon2seq := proc (n) local a, b, P; 
P := []; 
for a in ConjugacyClass([[1, 2]], Symm(n)) do 
for b in ConjugacyClass([[1, 2]], Symm(n)) do 
if PermSupport(a)[2] <= PermSupport(b)[2] 
then P := [op(P), [a, b]] 
end if 
end do 
end do; 
return P
end proc
```

Monseq(3) = $$[[(2,3),(2,3)],[(2,3),(1,3)],[(1,3),(2,3)],[(1,3),(1,3)],[(1,2),(2,3)],[(1,2),(1,3)],[(1,2),(1,2)]
 $$

Comment: This question is probably more suitable for ask.sagemath.org.

Comment: Yes, I agree, I was not aware of this org, I will post there from now on. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `cycle_tuples` is helpful: it returns a list of tuples which represent the permutation. In the case of transpositions, this list has length 0, and we want to compare the 1st element in each such tuple:

```
G = SymmetricGroup(3)
g = G((1,2))
C = ConjugacyClass(G,g)
P = []
for a in C:
    for b in C:
        if a.cycle_tuples()[0][1] <= b.cycle_tuples()[0][1]:
            P.append([a,b])
```

Then `P` should be equal to

```
[[(2,3), (2,3)],
 [(2,3), (1,3)],
 [(1,2), (2,3)],
 [(1,2), (1,2)],
 [(1,2), (1,3)],
 [(1,3), (2,3)],
 [(1,3), (1,3)]]
```

For the comparison you could instead use the `support` method: if `a = (1,2)`, then `a.support()` is the set `{1, 2}`, so `sorted(a.support())` would be `[1, 2]` and `sorted(a.support())[1]` would be `2`. Or use `max(a.support())`.

Comment: How did you know about this command there is documentation?

Comment: I used tab-completion (“a.TAB”) and looked for likely names of methods. Then “a.support?” gives documentation.

Comment: In my Jupiter notebook, I cannot autocomplete a command. Is there package we have to install?

Comment: Sage notebooks in Jupyter should provide completion. Describe the problem as completely as you can on ask.sagemath.org for help troubleshooting.

Comment: (To use the commands I suggested, `a` first has to be an element of `G`, for example `a = list(C)[0]`.)